# Working with Visual Studio 2005 projects in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, projects-and-solutions

I've received a new computer from my employer. This time I don't want to maintain several versions of Visual Studio (although I know they work great side-by-side). Can I work with an ongoing VS2005 project in VS2008? By 'working' I mean the ability to **open**, **modify**, and **save** back to the *original* format.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this without editing the .csproj files. You'll need to change the "ToolsVersion" attribute in the project header.

Comment: Maybe there's some kind of an add-on to export to a previous version?

Comment: Not that I've ever heard of. Why do you need both versions? VS2008 can target .NET 2.0.

Comment: Because I cannot convince my foreign colleagues to switch to VS2008. Stupid, I know

Comment: @Kerido: maybe they'll switch to 2008 in a month when 2010 comes out. They'd do better to take the chance to try VS2010 for free, right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain to csproj files, when opening in VS2008 it will convert it. Make sure you have a backup.

Comment: This is not an option, because whenever I modify the converted VS2008 version, the two project files are no more in sync.

Comment: Then @John Saunders is your only option.